# Can't keep pointcloud in Rviz when building a map with rtabmap_ros

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I have a problem with the rtabmap. I am able to see "parts" of the map created in Rviz on mapData topic.
Actually, I have a stereo camera and I can see the result of rtabmap. But I move the camera the previous results is not staying visible.

To launch rtabmap node, I am using the parameters which are in the *rtabmap_ros/launch/demo/demo_stereo_outdoor.launch* and I am also using the following configuration file for rviz *rtabmap_ros/launch/config/demo_stereo_outdoor.rviz*. These two files works whe I use them to open a bag file like in the stereo_outdoor_mapping tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorMapping).

But when I am using rosrtabmap-databaseViewer on the database created, I can see all the images taken during the last execution of Rviz.

Question :
Is there any call to make to some rtabmap services (like publish_map) or is there another option to add in an other file ?

ps : i have a warning on the TF_OLD_DATA again even if I am using the following line in the rtabmap node :

```
<param name="wait_for_transform" type="bool" value="true"/>
```

I have also tried to use a map_assembler node without success :

```
<!-- Grid map assembler for rviz -->
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="map_assembler" name="map_assembler">
     <param name="occupancy_grid" type="bool" value="true"/>
     <remap from="mapData" to="mapData_optimized"/>
     <remap from="grid_projection_map" to="/map"/>
</node>
```

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209662/can%27t-keep-pointcloud-in-rviz-when-building-a-map-with-rtabmap_ros/) by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 379 on 2015-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For the "some parts of the map disappearing" with the [rtabmap_ros/MapCloud](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Map_Cloud_Display) rviz plugin, you can disable its node filtering parameters to keep **all** clouds shown:

- Set "Node filtering radius (m)" to 0.
- Set "Node filtering angle (degrees)" to 0.

The demo stereo launch files you are referring are working only for the specified bags (which require "use_sim_time=true"). On a robot, you should remap the topics sent from the ros bag and set "use_sim_time=false". When simulating the clock, the TF_OLD_DATA warning can happen when you are replaying the same rosbag: the second time, all timestamps are in the past.

In the [demo launch file](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorMapping#Launch), the [map_assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#map_assembler) subscribes to **/rtabmap/mapData_optimized** topic (note the rtabmap namespace). If mapData_optimized is not published, map_assembler will do nothing.

For your specific question: " Is there any call to make to some rtabmap services (like publish_map) or is there another option to add in an other file ?", which kind of file do you want to add? If you want to process another bag file with the same launch file, record a bag with the same topics recorded in the [demo bag files](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/StereoOutdoorMapping#ROS_bags). Example:

```
$ rosbag info stereo_outdoorA.bag 
path:        stereo_outdoorA.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    3:55s (235s)
start:       Nov 11 2014 15:28:20.90 (1415737700.90)
end:         Nov 11 2014 15:32:16.65 (1415737936.65)
size:        668.3 MB
messages:    54083
compression: none [848/848 chunks]
types:       sensor_msgs/CameraInfo      [c9a58c1b0b154e0e6da7578cb991d214]
             sensor_msgs/CompressedImage [8f7a12909da2c9d3332d540a0977563f]
             tf2_msgs/TFMessage          [94810edda583a504dfda3829e70d7eec]
topics:      /stereo_camera/left/camera_info_throttle              3741 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo     
             /stereo_camera/left/image_raw_throttle/compressed     3753 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
             /stereo_camera/right/camera_info_throttle             3741 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo     
             /stereo_camera/right/image_raw_throttle/compressed    3745 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CompressedImage
             /tf                                                  39103 msgs    : tf2_msgs/TFMessage          (2 connections)
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [F.Brosseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/22477/f.brosseau/) on 2015-05-26**:
I just set filter_radius and filter_angle to 0 and it works.
Thanks a lot